# SQL Server Vector Index

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, indexing, full-text-search

I would like to create a vector index for a database table in SQL Server. In my case, I have 256-dimensional vectors (numerical representations of the text contents of each row, derived from some NLP methods). However, SQL Server unfortunately does not seem to include array functionality (numerical vector data type).

Some potential solutions are offered here: https://www.sqlshack.com/implement-array-like-functionality-sql-server/. For instance, I could create a table with one column for each entry of the vector. Is there a more elegant (performant) way?

---

Background: I am implementing a semantic search feature for my database using MS Machine Learning Services (Python), that is, I want to be able to compare vector representations of query texts to the index (using cosine similarity). I know that there is also a full-text search feature for SQL server. Currently, I do not use it because it provides too little control over the pre-processing of the rather messy text fields in my database.

Comment: You could create your own CLR datatype to store the data. I don't think that you're able to add a custom index implementation on top of that though. It still may be useful to you though insofar as you can add methods to the type to perform operations that are important to you (e.g. comparisons).

Comment: What would you be doing with these values? One possibility is a SQLCLR type, storing the data in a compacted `byte[]` array

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas so far. Currently I am experimenting with dumping the array as a binary object into a single column - e.g, in Python code using `pickle.dumps(array)`.